# Azure Data Factory: Moving data from Table Storage to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, cortana-intelligence

While moving data from Table Storage to SQL Azure, is it possible to obtain only the Delta (The data that hasn't been already moved) using Azure Data Factory?

A more detailed explanation:
There is an Azure Storage Table, which contains some data, which will be updated periodically. And I want to create a Data Factory pipeline which moves this data to an SQL Azure Database. But during each move I only want the newly added data to be written to SQL DB. Is it possible with Azure Data Factory?

Answer (score 1):

See more information on azureTableSourceQuery and copy activity at this link : https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-table-connector/#azure-table-copy-activity-type-properties.

Also see this link for invoking stored procedure for sql: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-factory-azure-sql-connector/#invoking-stored-procedure-for-sql-sink

You can query each time on timestamp to achieve something similar to delta copy, but this is not true delta copy.

Comment: how do you delete data from table storage using data factory?